# True color в ncurses

Tags: terminal, ncurses

Как сделать чтобы `ncurses` использовал все цвета `r,g,b`?
делал `init_color(1,100,100,0)` - но это не работает
Использую `Gnome Terminal` на `Linux`. Он вроде поддерживает `True Color`
Где-то читал про какой-то `Konsole`, но так и не понял что это и как его в мой проект включить

Comment: Похоже, никак. http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_16MegaColors

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать установить в терминале переменную окружения `TERM=xterm-256color` будет не 16 цветов, а 256 (конечно не 32 бита).  `konsole` это основной терминал в KDE.